# Error while generating a signed apk in Android Studio

Tags: android, apk

I want to generate an apk file out of my project but I keep getting this error while generating the signed apk:

`Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class`

I'm searching since 6 hours for a solution now and I have tried nearly everything but I can't fix it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pake.lightbulb"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets.main
        {
            jni.srcDirs=[]
        }

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: Are you using Fresco by chance?  You may need to update your library to the latest version according to this ticket: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1493

Comment: One of your dependencies has a different version of support v4 and it's conflicting. Make sure all of your dependencies are using the same version

Comment: post your `gradle`

Comment: I posted my gradle now

Comment: Please don't post your `grade` file as image, but rather copy-paste it as code in the question, it is better for all.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `support-v4` library gets also included via the `play-services` dependency. To exclude it change the relevant dependency line of your  `gradle` to:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+')
{
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

To troubleshoot it more and inspect for other duplicates and conflicts, check the dependency tree command of gradle:

`gradle -q dependencies --configuration compile`

Comment: I changed that line of my gradle now, but I keep getting the same error. What do you mean with checking the dependency tree command of gradle?

Comment: Shows the dependencies that your project uses, it is useful to spot any conflicts or duplicates as in your situation. You can read more here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies

Comment: I sadly dont understand how to do that. I don't really know anything about Android Studio. I just imported my app and want to create an apk file out of it now.

Comment: Try to remove your last dependency `compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')` and undo the change suggested in this answer: `exclude module: 'support-v4'`

Comment: Wow! It actually worked! But now I have another problem, if I want to open the app, it keeps crashing.

Comment: check your logcat and post the exception stacktrace

Comment: I tried to open the app on my real device. How can I do that?